# Analyzing a Mini Kernel Dump File with WinDbg: how can I get the PID of the offending process?

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg

I have a Mini Kernel Dump File and

`PROCESS_NAME:  svchost.exe`

Is it possible to get the PID that `svchost.exe` had?

Comment: `!process 0 0 svchost` would list all svchost processes in a full kernel dump. I assume that this does not work

Comment: @ThomasWeller `2: kd> !process 0 0 svchost` says `Unable to read _LIST_ENTRY @ fffff801ecd93450`

Comment: Check if you can issue a `!teb`. If it works you'll have a `ClientId` line with two numbers in hex: the 1st one is the pid and the 2nd is the tid. If you have the EPROCESS structure of the faulty process, you can do `dt _eprocess <eprocess address> UniqueProcessId`. There are other ways to do that but they get increasingly complicated and will probably not work with a small dump.  I'd also verify the dump with `dumpchk.exe`, just in case.

Comment: @Neitsa `2: kd> !teb` says `TEB at 0000003ea1d93000
error InitTypeRead( TEB )...`; anyway, thank you for `dumpchk.exe`, I was unaware of it!

Comment: you possibly have a corrupt dump   try looking at raw data the dump is a collection of streams  if you need a nudge take a look at [this](https://github.com/blabberer/pydmpchk) for dissecting it raw